# how can set different type of data to different colorbars in a plot by gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, colorbar

I want to plot some data that belongs to 10 different classes with different 10 color-bars, I scaled each classes to lie in different intervals. but this code has some errors:

## warning:

Number of pixels cannot be factored into integers matching grid. N = 5999  K = 60

## code:

anyone can help me?
every help is appreciated.

```
unset key
set terminal eps enhanced 
set output "t62.eps"
set xrange[0:0.5]
set yrange[0:6]
set palette model RGB
set palette model RGB defined (0 "green", 1 "dark-green", 1 "yellow", 2 "dark-yellow", 2 "red", 3 "dark-red" , 3 "blue" , 4 "dark-blue" )

set cbrange [ 0.00000 : 10.00000 ] noreverse nowriteback
set pm3d explicit at b
set palette defined ( 0 '#7FFF00', 1 '#008000', 1 '#FFFF00', 2 '#FF8C00', 2 '#FF0000', 3 '#800000', 3 '#DDA0DD', 4 '#4B0082', 4 '#B0C4DE', 5 '#191970',  5 '#00BFFF', 6 '#00008B', 6 '#C0C0C0', 7 '#000000', 7 '#FFEFD5', 8 '#8B4513', 8 '#BDB76B', 9 '#556B2F', 9 '#40E0D0', 10 '#2F4F4F' )
plot 'opplot2.txt' u 2:1:4 w image
```

Comment: In gnuplot 4.6, this warning could be due to missing datapoints (e.g. nan or inf values). It seems that this is fixed in gnuplot 5.0.

Comment: Do you have a regular grid (equidistant steps) and properly formatted data file with appropriate new lines?